# Ruby Devise sign up with AJAX not getting json response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ajax, devise

I have followed this tutorial: https://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-set-up-devise-ajax-authentication-with-rails-4-0/ ***And am using rails 5.1***.

I have implemented the json response in the controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  respond_to :json
end
```

And when I call the ajax I only get an `Html/Text` response:

```
function createUser(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: window.urls.createUser,
        data: {
            authenticity_token: $("meta[name=csrf-token]").attr("content"),
            user: grabOrderFormUserData()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Data: " + data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //console.log("error");
        }
    })
}
```

That call works fine, but returns the HTML page of the sign up.
The url I use is  `createUser: hostUrl + '/users/'`

What did I miss?

And no, if I add `.json` to my url, it will respond with 500 error code.

Comment: Have you read Troubleshooting part of this article (about rake routes)?

Comment: @kolas Rake routes?

Comment: about adding devise_for :users, :controllers => {sessions: 'sessions', registrations: 'registrations'}  to route.rb

Comment: Any luck with this ? I have a similar issue

Comment: @AakashUniyal Nope, I made a custom request and manually signed up using devise functions

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to mention `dataType: "json"` with your ajax call , try this

```
function createUser(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: window.urls.createUser,
        type: "POST",
        data: {`enter code here`
            authenticity_token: $("meta[name=csrf-token]").attr("content"),
            user: grabOrderFormUserData()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Data: " + data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //console.log("error");
        }
    })
}
```

and also in your controller try to call this block in case if you are not getting json response,

```
respond_to do |format|
     format.json { 
        render json: {.....}
     }
end
```

thank you.